# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing, When i call an jsp page everytime i got this exception

Tags: java, jsp

I am Integrating NSDL Pan API
but when I call a JSP page using the controller
I got this exception
I am facing this exception for the first time

This is My JSP Page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <%-- <div class="light-bg mt-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="sub-heading">
                                            <h4>Applicant Information</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="text-field-label">Aadhar<span
                                            class="text-danger"></span></label> <form:input id="aadhaar" path="applicantDto.aadhaar"
                                            name="aadhaar" class="form-control input-box" type="text"
                                            placeholder="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" maxlength="12"
                                            autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly"/>
                                            <span id="error_app_aadhaar" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> --%>
                        <div class="light-bg mt-1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="sub-heading">
                                        <h4>Applicant Details</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="text-field-label">Title<span
                                            class="text-danger"></span></label><br /> <form:select id="appli_title" 
                                            name="appli_title" data-placeholder="Select Title" path=""
                                            class="select select2-hidden-accessible input-box"
                                            tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"  >
                                            <option value="0" selected="selected" >Please
                                                Select</option>
                                            <option value="1" >Shri</option>
                                            <option value="2">Smt</option>
                                            <option value="3">Kumari</option>
                                        </form:select>
                                        <span id="error_app_title" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group" id="l_name_div">
                                        <label class="text-field-label">Last Name / Surname <span
                                            class="text-danger"></span></label> <form:input id="l_name" name="l_name" value="" path="applicantDto.lastName"
                                            class="form-control input-box" 
                                            placeholder="Last Name / Surname" maxlength="25"
                                            autocomplete="off"/>
                                            <span id="error_app_l_name" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group" id="f_name_div">
                                        <label class="text-field-label">First Name<span
                                            class="text-danger"></span></label> <form:input id="f_name" name="f_name" value="" path="applicantDto.firstName"
                                            class="form-control input-box" 
                                            placeholder="First Name" maxlength="25" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            <span id="error_app_f_name" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="text-field-label">Middle Name<span
                                            class="text-danger"></span></label> <form:input id="m_name" name="m_name" value="" path="applicantDto.middleName"
                                            class="form-control input-box" 
                                            placeholder="Middle Name" maxlength="25" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            <span id="error_app_m_name" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group" id="date_of_birth_div">
                                        <label>Date of Birth<span class="text-danger"></span></label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <form:input id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth"  path="applicantDto.dob" class="form-control date-input" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
                                                <label class="input-group-btn" for="date_of_birth">
                                                    <span class="btn btn-default calendor-btn">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="font-size:24px"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>
                                                <span id="error_app_dob" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="form-group" id="gender_div">
                                        <label>Gender<span class="text-danger"></span></label><br />
                                        <form:select id="gender" name="gender" path="applicantDto.gender"
                                            class="select select2-hidden-accessible input-box w-100"
                                            tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <option value="N" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
                                            <option value="M" >Male</option>
                                            <option value="F">Female</option>
                                            <option value="T">Transgender</option>
                                        </form:select>
                                        <span id="error_app_gender" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="text-field-label"><h5>Name that you
                                                would like printed on PAN card</h5></label> <form:input id="name_card" path="applicantDto.nameOnPanCard"
                                            name="name_card" class="form-control input-box"  
                                            maxlength="85" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            <span id="error_app_pan_name" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="sub-heading">
                                            <h5>Have you ever been known by any other name?</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="chkYes"> <form:radiobutton id="chkYes" path="applicantDto.knownByOtherName"
                                        name="chkPinNo"  value="Y" class="knownByOtherName"/> Yes
                                    </label> <label for="chkNo"> <form:radiobutton id="chkNo" path="applicantDto.knownByOtherName"
                                        name="chkPinNo" checked="checked"  value="N" class="knownByOtherName"/> No
                                    </label>
                                    <div id="dvPinNo" style="display: none">
                                        <div class="container p-0 mt-2">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="text-field-label">Title<span
                                                            class="text-danger"></span></label><br /> <form:select
                                                            id="appli_other_title" name="appli_other_title" path="applicantDto.otherTitle"
                                                            data-placeholder="Select Title"
                                                            class="select select2-hidden-accessible input-box"
                                                            tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                                            <option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
                                                            <option value="1" >Shri</option>
                                                            <option value="2">Smt</option>
                                                            <option value="3">Kumari</option>
                                                        </form:select>
                                                        <span id="error_app_other_title" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="text-field-label">Last Name /
                                                            Surname <span class="text-danger"></span>
                                                        </label> <form:input id="other_l_name" name="other_l_name" path="applicantDto.otherLastName"
                                                            class="form-control input-box" 
                                                            placeholder="Last Name / Surname" maxlength="25"
                                                            autocomplete="off"/>
                                                            <span id="error_app_other_l_name" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="text-field-label">First Name<span
                                                            class="text-danger"></span></label> <form:input id="other_f_name" path="applicantDto.otherFirstName"
                                                            name="other_f_name" class="form-control input-box"
                                                             placeholder="First Name" maxlength="25" 
                                                            autocomplete="off"/>
                                                            <span id="error_app_other_f_name" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="text-field-label">Middle Name<span
                                                            class="text-danger"></span></label> <form:input id="other_m_name" path="applicantDto.otherMiddleName"
                                                            name="other_m_name" class="form-control input-box"
                                                             placeholder="Middle Name" maxlength="25"
                                                            autocomplete="off"/>
                                                            <span id="error_app_other_m_name" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I got this Exception

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [/views/applicant_details.jsp] at line [39]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/views/applicant_details.jsp] at line [39]

36:                                 <div class="col-sm-4">
37:                                     <div class="form-group">
38:                                         <label class="text-field-label">Title<span
39:                                             class="text-danger"></span></label><br /> <form:select id="appli_title" 
40:                                             name="appli_title" data-placeholder="Select Title" path=""
41:                                             class="select select2-hidden-accessible input-box"
42:                                             tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"  >


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:611)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:490)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.views.applicant_005fdetails_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fselect_005f0(applicant_005fdetails_jsp.java:359)
    org.apache.jsp.views.applicant_005fdetails_jsp._jspService(applicant_005fdetails_jsp.java:166)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.46

```
I am tired of This
I don't know what can I do
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved This error by adding this code

```
@RequestMapping(value="form", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String form() {
        System.out.println("In Controller");
        return "applicant_details";
    }
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value="form", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String form(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute("applicantDto") Model model) {
        System.out.println("In Controller");
        System.out.println(model.toString());
        return "applicant_details";
    }
```

Thank you,
Stackoverflow